# How to set background color of HTML table for output to PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, itext

I have some HTML that I am rendering out to a PDF file with iTextSharp. However, I'm having some issues with setting the background colors of my table cells. Here is some sample HTML I am using:

```
<tr align="center">
<th width="16%" colspan="2" style="height: 16px; font-weight:bold;" color="#FF0000">Test Colored Text</th>
<td width="28%" colspan="2" style="height: 16px;"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litData" /></td>
</tr>
```

The **<th>** element in this case has some properties being set via the **style** property. In this case height and font-weight. Also, I have a **color** property being set on this as well.

This outputs a table to my PDF file where the "Test Colored Text" text is set to Red as per the **color** property. My goal is to set the background color of this cell, and have tried adding the css property **background-color** to the **style** tag with no luck.

Being that the **color** property is being read I tried a few other properties to see if any would take:
**background-color**, 
**backgroundcolor**, 
**basecolor**

However, none of these effectively change the background color of the cell in the PDF file.

My question is, what is the property name that it is looking for to set the background color? I've looked around a bit and have only found ways where people do this buy building the cells in the code, which for me is not an option as I am stuck with this HTML that needs to be styled.

**Edit:** Using the **bgcolor** property sets the background of the cell. Thanks Louis!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using the `bgcolor` attribute.

```
<th  bgcolor="#FFFF00" color="#FF0000">Test Colored Text</th>
```

Comment: @user1048281 Wonderful. By the way, did you know that instead of editing your question, you can just click the checkmark to accept an answer?